# How does Emotional Freedom Technique (EFT) work?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, therapy, emotional-freedom-technique

There is mounting evidence that EFT, a form of therapy which combines cognitive, exposure therapy along with acupuncture point stimulation is effective -
[EFT for PTSD question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23876/evidence-for-eft-emotional-freedom-technique-for-ptsd)

What are the biological evidence for the efficacy for EFT?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of studies that seem to outline some possible mechanisms for how EFT works.

A [2012 study of salivary cortisol of 83 subjects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22986277) found that a significant decrease after one hour of clinical EFT treatment.

> decrease in cortisol level (-24.39%; SE, 2.62) compared with the decrease observed in the SI (-14.25%; SE, 2.61) and NT (-14.44%; SE, 2.67) groups (p < 0.03)

In a [2018 randomised study of 16 subjects with PTSD](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0890117116661154?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3dpubmed) having done 10 clinical EFT treatment found genetic changes.

> Significant differences (P < .05) were found for 6 genes—chemokine receptor 3 (CXCR3), interleukin 18 (IL-18), interleukin 10 receptor beta, tumor necrosis factor alpha–induced protein 6, leukocyte-endothelial cell adhesion molecule 1 (selectin L), and interferon-induced transmembrane protein 1. These target genes are generally known to be involved in the regulation of cellular immunity and inflammation and are associated with stress.

One of the mechanisms EFT is thought to work is through acupuncture stimulation. This review article describes [2009 study of 48 subjects treated with acupuncture](http://www.acupmedvet.com/artigos%20cient%C3%ADficos/Hui_2010_AutonomicNeuroscience.pdf) found -

> decreased activity in limbic and paralimbic regions including the medial prefrontal, medial parietal and medial temporal lobes, along with increased activity in the sensorimotor cortices and select paralimbic structures.